# Extension of curves in a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

In a proof in a book (differential geometric structures Poor), I've read an extension of a curve in a proof:

Let G be a Lie group, $a<b<c<d$, $f:(a,c) \longrightarrow G$ smooth function. Then exists $f^*:(a,d) \longrightarrow G$ smooth function that $f^*|_{(a,b)}=f|_{(a,b)}$

Is it true? What is the proof of it?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: are you sure? Notice that $b < c$ strictly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality you can assume $a < 0 < b$ (else just subtract something from all of the real numbers).

Choose $e \in (b,c)$.

Let $h(x)$ be a smooth function defined on $(a,d)$ such that it is equal to 1 on $(a,e)$ and equal to 0 on $(c,d)$ (you can use the standard bump function construction).

Let $\gamma(x) = x \cdot h(x)$, so $\gamma(x) = x$ for $x\in (a,b)$. 
Observe that by construction $\gamma |_{(b,d)}$ takes values in $[0,c)$.

Let $f^*(x) = f\circ \gamma(x)$.